# OSError: [WinError -1073741795] Windows Error 0xc000001d [Windows API and Python]

Tags: python, winapi

I am working on an app and making it by using Windows API and Python. I already have a main window, but now I want a dialog box. I have tried functions like `CreateDialog` and `CreateDialogIndirectParamA` to make a dialog box, but that did not work. Now, I am trying to make a second window just like I made the main window. The second window is created, but is destroyed immediately and that error is throw. This is the error message: `DispatchMessageA(lpmsg) OSError: [WinError -1073741795] Windows Error 0xc000001d`. I have no clue what is causing the error or what it means. Please help me. I need it to work for a school project. Thank you!

You will need three files to make the app

main.py: https://gist.github.com/aryan-debug/fd579f01f42f92bea2369a3ec14e80ff

user32.py: https://gist.github.com/aryan-debug/cd3d1c34a18f9a8e46f9fb5481761384

button.py: https://gist.github.com/aryan-debug/8f145cb1b14a206af99ac72e430b53a6

Comment: First, extract a [mcve]. Then, search for the error message online.

Comment: I can't really extract a minimal reproducible example because my friend tried to do the same I am doing. We have very similar code but mine doesn't work for some reason. This is what I want to find out. What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Compare your code with your friend's. Also, that your friend tried the same is not a reason you can't extract a [mcve].

Comment: `0xc000001d` is actually an NTSTATUS that translates to: `STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION: An attempt was made to execute an illegal instruction`

Comment: can you please explain what illegal instruction I made?